# how to change hostname with my FQDN on GCE

Tags: server, vps, google-compute-engine

i've the problem to change permanently my hostname on my instance Google Compute Engine. How to change permanent hostname with my FQDN?

Thank you

Matteo

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].